# French TV sites with English subtitles

Tags: anglais, ressources, télévision

I would like to improve my listening abilities post French A-level. I am currently struggling to find any sites where they have French TV/movies but with English subtitles. Occasionally you can find videos that do this on YouTube, but the quality of the subtitles is often not great.

Comment: my tags are probably off, but i couldnt find any suitable!

Comment: Well one thing you could do is buy DVD's/BluRays already. The tv channel TV5 if you manage to get it is also often broadcasting in French with French subtitles, if it can help. Please note though that subtitles are not a litteral transcription of the speach. Sometimes it will be the same, sometimes what is said just can't fit into the rules for subtitles editing, so the subtitles are only ceonveying the same meaning, but with different words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little googling may help. Some suggestions follow

http://jean-nicolaslefle.viabloga.com/news/films-franca-304-s-soust-304-tres-en-franca-304-s

http://flecampus.ning.com/profiles/blogs/cinema-dossier-pedagogique-fle

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=phwihXR3VSM